# wiremock how to ignore repeated request being recorded

Tags: wiremock

I am starting Wiremock server and registering the mapping and starting the recording for that stub as below. I am looking for option through which I can ignore repeated request getting recorded.

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(9000).usingFilesUnderDirectory("/test"));
wireMockServer.start();

WireMock wireMockClient = new WireMock(9000);
wireMockClient.startStubRecording("https://test.com:443");
wireMockClient.register(any(urlMatching("/credit"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("https://test.com:443")));

WireMock wireMockClient2 = new WireMock(9000);
wireMockClient2.startStubRecording("https://test:5134");
wireMockClient2.register(any(urlMatching("/debit"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("https://test.com:5134")));

// code which makes calls to  http://localhost:9000/credit and http://localhost:9000/debit

wireMockClient.stopStubRecording();
wireMockServer.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you'll have to pass in a recording specification. Something like the following should work

```
wireMockClient.startStubRecording(
    recordSpec()
         .forTarget("https://test.com:443")
         .ignoreRepeatRequests()
    );
```

[More information here under the "Customising Your Recordings" section](http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/)